# Update All Records in Rails Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am making an app in which users place bets on future scenarios like "Who Will Win American Idol?"

The user places his bet (referred to in the code as a prop).

Then later, the admin chooses the correct answer by editing the answer of the bet.

I want then, to check in the database to see whether the answer that each user has matches the answer that the admin has just provided.

I am trying to do something like this

```
  def update
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])

    @prop = Prop.find(params[:id])
    @answer = Answer.find(params[:id])

    @prop.update(prop_params)

    User.all.map 
     { |user|
      #the code here is called once for each user
      # user is accessible by 'user' variable


      if @answer.choice == @prop.choice
        puts "hello"
        @user.score += 7
        @user.save
      else
        @user.score -= 7
        @user.save

      end
     }

  end
```

What is the best way to accomplish my goal?

Comment: it seems like you look for `update_all`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be simply like this:

```
def update
  @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
  @prop = Prop.find(params[:id])
  @answer = Answer.find(params[:id])

  @prop.update(prop_params)
  score_change = @answer.choice == @prop.choice ? 7 : -7
  User.update_all("score = score + #{score_change}")
end
```

**Explanation**

This will return 7 or -7 as you want

```
score_change = @answer.choice == @prop.choice ? 7 : -7
```

Then we just update all user in a single query, don't need to iterate over each of user

```
User.update_all("score = score + #{score_change}")
```

Under the hook, this sql will be generated:

```
UPDATE "users" SET score = score + 7
```

Or

```
UPDATE "users" SET score = score + -7
```

Comment: Wow, you nailed it. Can you please explain your code a little bit. If you could explain how it works, especially the last two lines, that would be really helpful!

Comment: There is a problem with this solution upon implementation. As of now, the score of every user changes each time that the answer to the prop changes. I need to make it so only the score of the user changes if their answer to that specific prop is different from that of the prop answer. Can we do this?

Comment: In other words, we do need to iterate through each user and see whether they have answered on that prop.

Comment: This is what I have now
```

  def update
     @answer = Answer.find(params[:id])
     @prop = Answer.find(@answer.prop_id)

     @user = User.find(@answer.user_id)
     @prop.update(prop_params)

       Answer.all.map
        if @answer.choice.to_s == @prop.choice.to_s
          @user.score  += 5
        else
           @user.score -= 5
        end
        @user.save

  end
```

Comment: @CodeYogi I think I may raise another thread to describe in detail!

Comment: OK, great. Please keep me in the loop.